# Deep comparing object props in React not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am optimizing performance of a React app by reducing unnecessary re-renders. The component I am working on receives a single prop containing an object with many keys including array of objects. I am using `shouldComponentUpdate` to check for changes in prop, but it's not working as expected:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (!(_.isEqual(nextProps, this.props))) {
        console.log('difference', _.differenceWith(nextProps, this.props));
        return true;
    }

  return false;
}
```

`isEqual` is a method from Lodash for deep comparing objects. `differenceWith` is a Lodash method for finding difference in two objects. The weird thing is that using `isEqual` does not reduce re-renderings, and `differenceWith` prints an empty array `[]`. But if I use `JSON.stringify` instead of `isEqual`, re-renders are reduced by half, but `differenceWith` still prints `[]`.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    if ( JSON.stringify(nextProps) !== JSON.stringify(this.props) ) {
        console.log('difference', _.differenceWith(nextProps, this.props));
        return true;
    }

  return false;
}
```

Why is there a difference in behaviour of `isEqual` and `JSON.stringify` when they are essentially doing the same thing, although in a different way (note that `isEqual` is also order sensitive)?

What is the best way to avoid re-renderings here?

Comment: If your Object is nested you need to either use lodash `deepClone` or `JSON.parse(JSON.strinfiy(Obj))`

Comment: I don't see how this is going to help? `deepClone` is for cloning objects which is not required here and there is no sense in converting an object to json and then back to object..!

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate`,`PureComponent` and `React.memo` does shallow comparing. So re-render doesn't happen if the nested data changes.

Answer (score 2):

> 1 - Why is there a difference in behaviour of isEqual and JSON.stringify when they are essentially doing the same thing, although in a different way (note that isEqual is also order sensitive)?

Take a look on what I found [here](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/33-how-to-compare-2-objects).

> Well that depends. For JSON.stringify(), the order matters. So if the key-value pair are ordered differently in the two objects but are the same, it will return false. Whereas it doesn't matter in Lodash isEqual, it will return true as along as the key-value pair exists.
>
> ```
> const one = {
>   fruit: '',
>   energy: '255kJ',
> };
>
> const two = {
>   energy: '255kJ',
>   fruit: '',
> };
>
>
> // Using JavaScript
> JSON.stringify(one) === JSON.stringify(two); // false
>
> // Using Lodash
> _.isEqual(one, two); // true
> ```

This means that you `JSON.stringify` can work, but not in all cases, so probably you shouldn't use it for your case.

I also found a [benchmark](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/1854/0/lodash-isequal-test) that compares both. `JSON.stringify` is better for less deep nested objects, but `_.isEqual` gets better with more deep nested objects.

[_.differenceWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#differenceWith) is used to compare arrays wich receives 3 parameters, 2 are arrays to compare and the third one is the comparator.

Doing this `_.differenceWith(nextProps, this.props)` would be the same as `_.difference(nextProps, this.props)` as you can see in the docs

**_.differenceWith**

> This method is like _.difference except that it accepts comparator which is invoked to compare elements of array to values. The order and references of result values are determined by the first array. The comparator is invoked with two arguments: (arrVal, othVal).

**_.difference**

> Creates an array of array values not included in the other given arrays using SameValueZero for equality comparisons. The order and references of result values are determined by the first array.

So using one of this, will return a new array with the values different values. If it returns `[]` it means that the array have the same values **but it can be in a different other**.

`_.differenceWith` is good if you have an array of objects and you also want to compare the objects. This can be seen in the doc's example.

> ```
> var objects = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }];
>
> _.differenceWith(objects, [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }], _.isEqual);
> // => [{ 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }]
> ```

---

> 2 - What is the best way to avoid re-renderings here?

For your case, I recommend using `_.isEqual` because it compares exactly the order of an array and you can have objects with the same properties but in  different orders, and it will be the same.

---

Use said

> The weird thing is that using isEqual does not reduce re-renderings, and differenceWith prints an empty array []. But if I use JSON.stringify instead of isEqual, re-renders are reduced by half...

And I'm not sure why this happens, it deppends on alot of things, but you should definitely use `_.isEqual` if you want to compare state or props of a component.

You can also [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) and [`React.PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent), this might help in some cases.

And as you can see in the docs of `memo`

> If your function component renders the same result given the same props, you can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost in some cases by memoizing the result. This means that React will skip rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result.
>   ...
>   This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs

And the docs of `PureComponent`

> React.PureComponent is similar to React.Component. The difference between them is that React.Component doesn’t implement shouldComponentUpdate(), but React.PureComponent implements it with a shallow prop and state comparison.
>
> If your React component’s render() function renders the same result given the same props and state, you can use React.PureComponent for a performance boost in some cases.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Really appreciate that. However, using `React.PureComponent` won't help here because I have deeply nested object props. `React.memo` is also same, except that it's used for functional components.

Comment: @maverick just edit the question to answer the 2 questions you made in your question.

Comment: I wasn't answering my question. Rather just commenting on your solution..

Comment: After my edit, I give you the answer of the 2 questions you made in your question and also something that might help you. Hope it helps :)

Comment: This answer is fair. But @maverick you should probably not use `shouldComponentUpdate`,`PureComponent` and `React.memo` for deep check. Instead implement lazy loading.

Comment: It's hard to say to him implement lazy loading, we don't have any code or information of his application.

Comment: @Raviteja I know that lazy loading is the ideal solution here and I even looked at libraries like 'react-window', but unfortunately this component is from another npm module which I have no control over. I read somewhere that making props immutable helps in cases like above, but I am not sure how to implement it in this scenario?

Comment: Came across this..seems like using `isEqual` in `shouldComponentUpdate` is not a good idea. Check this tweet by Dan Abramov (he doesn't mention the solution though. I tried `react-fast-compare`, but strangely it doesn't work here, just like `isEqual` not working for me) - https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/915886716262797312?s=21

Comment: @maverick What I’m saying is if you try comparing nested objects, to avoid re-rendering you could end up comparing large amount of data which hinders performance.